# Signal representation in frequency domain

Tags: signal, fourier

My teacher taught me that the frequency representation of **time limited signal** will be **band unlimited**.

Also the frequency representation of **time unlimited** will be **band limited**.

i.e frequency domain representation of rectangular function will be sinc which is perfectly fine.[image: Fourier Transform]

Now,the question I have is if I have series of rectangular pulses

[image: Rectangular pulses]

Why don't I get band limited signal?

Comment: @RogerRowland what?

Comment: If we assume that A implies B, the absence of A **never** implies the absence of B. That's basic logic.

Comment: A time unlimited signal can be band unlimited. For example, Fourier Series tells us that a periodic signal, eg square wave, may have harmonics to infinity.

Answer (score 5):

Many people mistake necessary and sufficient reasons. Or if they don't mistake them, they don't spell out the difference, thinking it's obvious.

A time-limited signal *will* be unlimited in the frequency domain.

It's necessary that a signal be time unlimited, for it to be able to have a limited band in the frequency domain, but that's still not sufficient.

We can construct the spectrum of the rectangular pulse train using the convolution rule. As the rectangular pulse train is a pulse, convolved with an infinite series of impulses, its spectrum will be the spectrum of the pulse, *multiplied* by the spectrum of an infinite series of impulses.

As the spectrum of an infinite series of impulses is itself an infinite series of impulses, the total spectrum will still go out to infinity.

If instead you had a time signal that was a rectangular pulse convolved with (say) a Gaussian pulse (which is limited in both time and in its spectrum), then the spectrum of that would indeed be frequency limited.

Comment: A Gaussian pulse is not time or spectrum limited, although it does decay very fast in both. I'm not quite sure what a "Gaussian impulse" is, though?

Comment: I mean guassian pulse, an impulse is a delta of course. You are right theoretically of course, though wrong in practice, ie usefully. In order to get round what we really mean by DC, unlimited, infinity etc, it's often said the guassian pulse is 'compact' in both domains, thus fudging whether it goes to infinity or not. If you understand the difference, you know what I'm talking about, if you don't, then you don't need to know! It sounded like the OP didn't. If we look at how fast the power within a bandwidth approaches the total power, we can agree that 'compact' is a useful concept.

Comment: I come from a math/physics background, where we usually do pay attention to such distinctions :) Of course the concept you're talking about is indeed very useful often in practice, and in maths you then typically embody these in concepts of limits and/or decay rates of functions. However, as the OP is referring to a mathematical theorem, the distinction is crucial here: the Gaussian pulse would be a counterexample to the (corrected) claim unless by band/time limited you meant strictly zero outside some interval.

Comment: By the way, "compact" is a very overloaded term when it comes to Fourier transforms/functional analysis, as for example ["compactly supported"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Compact_support) means exactly that a function is *strictly zero* outside some compact set. I'm not disputing the usefulness of the concept you point to, or trying to change engineering parlance if that is indeed common terminology, just pointing out that there's a bit of a need to be careful here.

Comment: @Timo I come from a maths/physics/engineering background. To engineers I'm a mathematician, to mathematicians I'm a physicist, and to physicists I'm only an engineer! Engineers only deal with practicalities, so I tend to play fast and loose with limits. An engineer can build a synthesiser that can generate an irrational frequency, whereas a mathematician can prove you cannot find a rational representation of an irrational number. The difference is how good is an approximation? Irreducible noise provides the delta below which the error of an approximation is 'good enough'.

Comment: sure, I agree on the practical side. It's just that the question was about a mathematical theorem, in which case I believe it is necessary to apply mathematical rigor. Especially, as I said, in this case the theorem is *not true* for your definition of compact. So the engineering statement would be something along the lines (using your definition of compact) that there are signals which are compact in both the frequency- and time domains, one such example being the Gaussian pulse. That is basically the opposite of the mathematical theorem the OP was asking about.

Comment: @Timo I'll upvote your answer when you've posted it, if it turns out to be useful to the OP as well as being mathematically correct.

Comment: I'm not that eager to write an answer of my own, since I think yours is pretty good, except for the last paragraph, which is basically wrong. I'd upvote yours if you either removed the last paragraph, or then rewrote it such that you start by saying that the theorem, however, is not correct if you allow for approximately band limited signals, such as the Gaussian, and maybe discuss the difference between reality (noise limited resolution etc) versus statements concerning mathematical functions.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is wrong. The two true sentences are:

1. The frequency representation of a time limited signal will be band unlimited.
2. A band limited signal (in frequency) will be time unlimited.